# Нужна ли запятая перед деепричастным оборотом?

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

***"Не открывай дверь (?) не убедившись, кто за ней находится".***

Объясните, пожалуйста, в случае, если запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

***Не открывай двЕрь**, // не убедившись, **кто за ней нахОдится**.*

**[Тема: двери](https://15.%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%B4.%D1%80%D1%84/news/item/27787370/).**  Поэтому в данном тексте это слово логически подчеркнуто ударением.

```
Входные двери подъезда и квартиры должны надежно 
закрываться.

Дома вы или за пределами своего жилища, дверь всегда 
должна быть закрытой на замок. Никогда не открывайте 
дверь, не убедившись, кто за ней находится.
```

**Примечание.**  В других случаях **возможен** вариант без запятой, если ударением **нужно подчеркнуть** деепричастный оборот в роли **обстоятельства**.

Текст будет **такой**: *Оборудуйте дверь  глазком. **Никогда** не открывайте дверь **не убедИвшись**, // кто за ней нахОдится.*

В предложение добавлено наречие *никогда,* **усиливающее** отрицание.